# How to fix " '::iswblank' has not been declared" after Linker Settings and Search Directories have been changed

Tags: c++, mysql, mingw, codeblocks

I am follwing the tutorial for cpp and mysql connectiity, here's a link: https://sudarshan-cppmysql.blogspot.com/

After I change C::B configuration as per Step 6, below error appears.

Should I add any other path to the Linker Settings or Search Directories?

C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\cwctype|89|error: '::iswblank' has not been declared|

Comment: Can't help but notice that the blog post's screenshots are from the XP era. Are you using the exact same versions of software mentioned on the blog post? Or are you using modern versions?

Comment: Oh boy, that's written by a "professor" in 2016. It's a mess and it uses XP. I would possibly recommend avoiding using this blog as a serious learning resource.

Comment: I like how his paths are all for Dev-C++ but the instructions are about Code::Blocks. I have no idea what he's trying to accomplish by using two different toolchains in one project. Ignore him.

Comment: Thanks guys, is there anyone who could recommend good tutorial / site / source of knowledge to create simple cpp-mysql connectivity project?

Comment: I'm only one person, y'know :P

Answer (score 1):

The directories of the headers should be "\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include" and directory of libmysql.a should be "\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib".
That fixes the problem.
Thank you all for your answers (especially Lightness Races in Orbit who made me think :) ).